DOCKER ERROR: failed to solve: frontend grpc server closed unexpectedly
I am using docker on an EC2 linux/arm64 instance Since my last docker upgrade, I have been getting the following error
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -f
../containers/api/Dockerfile . -t api-test:latest
--target setup
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 493B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental
#2 DONE 0.6s

#3 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental@sha256:d2d402b6fa1dae752f8c688d72066a912d7042cc1727213f7990cdb57f60df0c
#3 CACHED Dockerfile:1 1 | >>> # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental 2 | 3 | # Build stage
ERROR: failed to solve: frontend grpc server closed unexpectedly make:
*** [run-tests] Error 1 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

The docker version
Client:

Version: 25.0.3
API version: 1.44
Go version: go1.20.12 Git
commit: 4debf41
Built: Wed Feb 28 00:29:45 2024
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Context: default

Server: Engine:

Version: 25.0.3
API version: 1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.20.12
Git commit: f417435
Built: Wed Feb 28 00:30:22 2024
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Experimental: false containerd:
Version: 1.3.2
GitCommit: ff48f57fc83a8c44cf4ad5d672424a98ba37ded6
runc: Version: 1.0.0-rc10
GitCommit: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
docker-init: Version: 0.19.0
GitCommit: de40ad0

On my M2 mac, it works fine with a newer version of docker

Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b.


Updated version of Docker with updated dependencies as seen here may resolve this.  Good luck.

The issue was with the versions of containerd and runc.
I updated the two to resolve the issue.
More details: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/5117
